# Peerjs Error: Could not get an ID from the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, webrtc, peerjs

using Peerjs cdn.It was working fine.Suddenly getting this error today Error: Could not get an ID from the server

```
 peer = new Peer();
```

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.3.1/dist/peerjs.min.js"></script>`

Even demo application given by peerjs documentation has this error now which was working fine before

https://jmcker.github.io/Peer-to-Peer-Cue-System/

Comment: Can you add more information and code so the community can help?

Comment: @M.AShahbazi done.Demo application of peerjs documentation also has same error now.updated link above

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem is known.

The public server is not available at the moment (cracked by botnet). The maintainer has already reported the cause of the issue on github: https://github.com/peers/peerjs/issues/937#issuecomment-1077781924

There is also a small guide on how to deploy your own server through Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

Install peer and peerjs from npm.
configure the following on the client js file.

```
const peer = new Peer(undefined, {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5001,
  path: '/'
});
```

Then while the initial server is running. open another terminal and run the following

```
 peerjs --port 5001
```

voila, you have started peerServer and now you can obtain the `peer.id.`

There are some other ways to too. please refer to this [link](https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server/blob/master/README.md) to explore those ways.